# Can you compare HMM's with different number of hidden states?

Tags: python, classification, hidden-markov-models, hmmlearn

I'm using Hidden Markov Models (hmmlearn to name the package being used) to classify different fishing gear based on vessel trajectories. For that purpose I trained 3 different HMM's, one for each fishing gear using prelabeled data. I then use the score method of hmmlearn to get the log-likelihood for an unknown sequence on each of the 3 models. I then pick the model belonging to the highest likelihood. While 2 models consist of 2 hidden states, one probably has 3 hidden states..
Now to my question: Can I use this approach when utilizing HMM's having different number of hidden states?

I got good results for the first two models using a 70/30 split with all models having the same number of hidden states but the latter only resulted in a 50% accuracy so I want to change the parameters a bit.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you have pre-labelled data, it seems you should set the number of states to be the number of classes in the pre-labelled data. If that's two, for example, then you could consider training multiple 2-state models and comparing their predictive accuracy on a test set.